# Flutter FutureProvider Value Not Updating In Builder Method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

### The Problem

I am building a basic app in Flutter that gets the user's location and displays nearby places in a swipe-card format similar to Tinder. I managed to implement geolocation however when using FutureProvider/Consumer I'm experiencing a weird bug where the user's relative distance to the place is overwritten with the first distance value in the card deck. Although I am new to flutter and the Provider package, I believe there is a simple fix to this.

***Side note:*** After searching around on Google, I attempted to use FutureProvider.value() to prevent the old value from updating but had no luck.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or direction!

### A Quick Demo

[image: FutureProvider Bug Demo]

### Packages Used

[image: packages used]

### card_swipe.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:swipe_stack/swipe_stack.dart';

import '../services/geolocator_service.dart';
import '../models/place.dart';

class CardSwipe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _currentPosition = Provider.of<Position>(context);
    final _placesProvider = Provider.of<Future<List<Place>>>(context);
    final _geoService = GeoLocatorService();

    return FutureProvider(
      create: (context) => _placesProvider,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        body: (_currentPosition != null)
            ? Consumer<List<Place>>(
                builder: (_, places, __) {
                  return (places != null)
                      ? Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0),
                              height: 600,
                              child: SwipeStack(
                                children: places.map((place) {
                                  return SwiperItem(builder:
                                      (SwiperPosition position,
                                          double progress) {
                                    return FutureProvider(
                                      create: (context) =>
                                          _geoService.getDistance(
                                              _currentPosition.latitude,
                                              _currentPosition.longitude,
                                              place.geometry.location.lat,
                                              place.geometry.location.lng),
                                      child: Consumer<double>(
                                          builder: (_, distance, __) {
                                        return (distance != null)
                                            ? Center(
                                                child: Card(
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    height: 200,
                                                    width: 200,
                                                    child: Center(
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(place.name),
                                                          Text(
                                                              '${(distance / 1609).toStringAsFixed(3)} mi'), // convert meter to mi
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            : Container();
                                      }),
                                    );
                                  });
                                }).toList(),
                                visibleCount: 3,
                                stackFrom: StackFrom.Top,
                                translationInterval: 6,
                                scaleInterval: 0.03,
                                onEnd: () => debugPrint("onEnd"),
                                onSwipe: (int index, SwiperPosition position) =>
                                    debugPrint("onSwipe $index $position"),
                                onRewind:
                                    (int index, SwiperPosition position) =>
                                        debugPrint("onRewind $index $position"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### geolocator_service.dart

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class GeoLocatorService {
  final geolocator = Geolocator();

  Future<Position> getLocation() async {
    return await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      locationPermissionLevel: GeolocationPermission.location,
    );
  }

  Future<double> getDistance(
      double startLat, double startLng, double endLat, double endLng) async {
    return await geolocator.distanceBetween(startLat, startLng, endLat, endLng);
  }
}
```

### place.dart

***Quick note:*** Place class does import a custom class called geometry.dart however this is purely for structuring the Place object and I'm certain it doesn't affect the bug. Therefore, it has been omitted.

```
import './geometry.dart';

class Place {
  final String name;
  final Geometry geometry;

  Place(this.name, this.geometry);

  Place.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson)
      : name = parsedJson['name'],
        geometry = Geometry.fromJson(
          parsedJson['geometry'],
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a key to the `SwiperItem` with some unique value (like the name of the place) since currently flutter thinks that the widget has stayed the same so the `Consumer` gets the state of the old topmost widget.
By adding the key you tell flutter that you removed the topmost widget and the new topmost is in fact the second widget

Comment: Thank you @PietervanLoon for your time. You're right this is definitely a great use for keys but it seems the `SwiperItem` widget doesn't have a `key` parameter and gives an error. I attempted to add it to the `Card` widget of `Center` but no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, definitely file an issue for that package to add the key parameters. But for now you can wrap the `SwiperItem` in a `KeyedSubtree` widget. It’s always important to put the key at the top of the tree that you want to be identified (so the SwiperItem in this case)

Comment: I'll definitely file an issue. After using `KeyedSubtree` the overwritten text is now gone but I am still experiencing a 'flash' of the old content after a card is removed. Here's a giphcat link to view the result https://gfycat.com/jampackedvapiddinosaur

Comment: I’m not familiar with the package so cannot help you there, perhaps open a new question (or an issue on github) for this part